# iFrame doesn't work in Frameset in IE

Tags: html

I have an iFrame in an HTML page that is loaded into a frameset frame. The source of the iFrame is a local HTML file. It works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE 11. The iFrame is blank.  The HTML page with the iFrame works fine in IE outside of the frameset.

Is there a solution to the problem?

Comment: `<frameset>` is [**deprecated**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset), and shouldn't be used at all. Use `<iframe>` instead.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help. Although I agree with you, we are using a legacy training template and have no choice.